# How to create multiple instance of mongos router server?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to configure a mongo sharded system. What I have configured right now is as follows:

2 Configuration servers
1 mongos router server
4 sharded servers

I've configured everything and its working perfectly. Now I want to try to create more instances or replica of my MONGOS server but unable to find any documentation about it. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Comment: `mongos` is a software component. and it is not bound to a dedicated hardware (like a config server). You can have any number of `mongos` instances. See this note: [Sharded Cluster Components - Number of mongos and Distribution](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/sharded-cluster-components/#number-of-mongos-and-distribution).

Answer (score 0):

mongos processes are independent. You can follow the same procedure you used to start your first one to start as many as you like.